# why potential becomes equal when capacitor are connected

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, capacitance

If we have a circuit as shown in which two capacitor are connected of unequal potential. [image]

Now if we close the switch the charge will flow till potential becomes equal.

But as we know $Q=CV$,

$V=Ed$  in this $V$ would be constant as $E$ is constant in a capacitor. Then how potential will become equal? 
Does the distance between capacitor changes or capacity of capacitor changes?

Comment: When you connect capacitors, the electric fields $E_i (i=1,2)$ in each capacitor changes, because you created a path for electrons to pass from one capacitor to the other. So the charges $Q_i$ change and hence $V_i$ and $E_i$ change as well. Neither the distances nor the capacities need to change, they are properties of each capacitor and fixed in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charges flow until the potential difference across each capacitor is the same.
In each capacitor the product $Ed$ will be the same.
The electric field in each capacitor will change  because the charge density on the capacitor plates changes.